# get time last updated github repository

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, git, github

How can I get the elapsed time since the last update in a github repository. I also want to get the main language.
[Picture of what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1thS.png)

> I want this data, to be able to use it on another website

I thought about doing it with JS, looking in the "id" and "class" tags, but i found this code on github web:

```
<li class="col-12 d-flex width-full py-4 border-bottom color-border-secondary private source" itemprop="owns" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Code">
  <div class="col-10 col-lg-9 d-inline-block">
    <div class="d-inline-block mb-1">
      <h3 class="wb-break-all">
        <a href="/nameRepo" itemprop="name codeRepository" >nameRepo</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="col-9 d-inline-block color-text-secondary mb-2 pr-4" itemprop="description">
           Description
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="f6 color-text-secondary mt-2">
        <span class="ml-0 mr-3">
  <span class="repo-language-color" style="background-color: #f1e05a"></span>
    <span itemprop="programmingLanguage">JavaScript</span>
  </span>
Updated <relative-time datetime="2021-05-27T08:02:25Z" class="no-wrap">May 27, 2021</relative-time>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have realized that it is not feasible, and even if it was, it is not practical at all.

I have thought that maybe with the API by "ssh", but it does not convince me either since I do not want a website that is constantly consuming those resources.

**You can brainstorm, without any problem**

Comment: Dates can be formatted with this: [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)   
`document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'Updated on ' + dateMoment.fromNow(true);`  
`document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = dateMoment.format("[Updated on] D MMM");`  
`document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = dateMoment.format("[Updated on] D MMM YYYY");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the github API's with JS

Any git repository that is public and specific. For example:

`https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPOSITORY/commits`

This information is in `commit.committer.date`  the file is a JSON

if it is a git repo found in your local file, you can use (in terminal):

`git --no-pager log -1 --format="%ai"`

Comment: I think it is the best answer that could be given. In case a googler is in a hurry, here is a sample of how it can be used and what should be modified: `$.getJSON('https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPO/commits', function (data) {// JSON result in `data` variable});`